# Defining classes with default values

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I understand that when I define a class I need to include self and **init**, but could someone help me with how I could define a class with a default value?

For instance:

```
class Student1():
    def __init__(self, college='University', gpa=3.2, credits=45):
        ...

class Student2():
    def __init__(self, college='Community College', gpa=3.8, credits=51):
        ...
```

I want to be able to have Student1.college to have the global value of 'University', Student2.college to have the global value of 'Community College', Student2.gpa to have the global value of 3.8 and Student1.gpa to have the global value of 3.2 so that when I use them in code later on they have the values I gave them.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT::

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, college, gpa, credits)
        self.college=college
        self.gpa=gpa
        self.credits=credits
Student1=Student("university", 3.2, 45)
Student2=Student("community college", 3.8, 51)
    def work(self, job='work study')
        self.job=job
```

So when I type Student1.college in the Python Shell it would return "university".

I want it so that both Student 1 and Student 2 have the "job" work study but when I type self.job in the Shell it says "Name:Error name "self" is not defined" Why?

Comment: I'm not sure why these are separate classes instead of being two different instances of the same class? Can you elaborate? Also what do you mean by 'global value' ?

Comment: @ChadS. I just need help starting my code basically. Later on in the defined class I want to be able to add to them. For instance, say Student1 takes a class worth 3 credits, I want to just simply be able to do Student1.credits + 3 to update it so that the original 45 credits gets updated to 48. If that makes sense.

Comment: I would suggest making a Student class that has a courses attribute that's a list of CourseTranscript instances where each CourseTranscript has a grade and a credits attribute. Then the student's 'credits' and 'gpa' would just be calculated from those CourseTranscripts.

Comment: This tutorial should get you 90% of the way there, please read it and update your question so we know how to help you. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: @BiRico your link helped a lot, but I am now stuck at a new location.. I updated my question.

Comment: It's fine on stackoverflow to edit questions and ask new questions, but try to keep it to one complete questions per post. If you edit the question, do you best to update the title and tags to match and remove anything from the original question that no longer makes sense. If the new question is very different than the original, consider creating a new question instead of editing. Also take a look at [this post about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few small issues with your code. First you need to finish defining you class before you create `student1` and `student2`. In python when you de-indent, you're telling the interpreter that you've reached the end of a block (ie a function, a class, a loop, or some other code block). If you want `work` to be a method of your class, it needs to be part of the class block for `Student`.

Second, afaict, you only ever set the `job` attribute in `work` but you never call `work`. It's often a good idea, but not required, to set every attribute to some default value in `init`.

And third, it seems like you're missing some `:` and have at least one indentation error. Try something like this:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, college, gpa, credits):
        self.college = college
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.credits = credits
        self.job = "no job"

    def setWork(self, job='work study'):
        self.job = job

student1 = Student("university", 3.2, 45)
student1.setWork()
student2 = Student("community college", 3.8, 51)
student2.setWork("Starbucks")

print student1.job
# work study
print student2.job
# Starbucks
```